# How can I make an image "jitter"?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

I have an image on my silverlight app and I want it to shake a little bit when the mouse is on top.

How can I achieve this? I'm really new to silverlight animations.

I need it to bounce a bit and tilt from left to right. Can anyone help?

Comment: So far I've only found this carousel excample that does image jitter - http://www.cellbi.com/DemoCenter/SvLite/Demo/SvFxDemo.html - but it's a paid for library and there's no source code showing how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

You could animate the `Image`'s `Margin` property, say from `-5 0 0 0` through `5 0 0 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also cause the top-left point of the image to rotate along a tight circle very quickly, depending on how you want the "jitter" to look...

There's also this demo from Nikhil Kothari:

http://www.nikhilk.net/Content/Posts/BouncingPlane/BouncingPlane.htm